# Why is my webpage in 300 something position in Google SERPs? Too little content?

Tags: seo, keywords, title

I made a webpage: http://pundaquitboat.michaelspages.com .
Unfortunately after changing the title of my webpage from *Pundaquit boat* to *Anawangin trip* finally my page was places between **300 and 400 position in Google SERPs** for my new keyword phrase "anawangin trip".

I'm just thinking is it the matter one of the following:

- **changing title meta tag**
- some **similarities of the page, I link to, on my page**:
  https://www.facebook.com/pages/Anawangin-AMAZING-PUNDAKIT-BOAT-TOURS/225675187453765
  (I took pics from that page, but changed pics' names)
- **too little content on my page**

Comment: The content on the page is too thin - bulk it up to about 500-1000 words on each page, if selling boat trips talk about the islands, waters that you boat though and talk about the kind of boat you have, and most important talk about how much fun people have on your boat. If you want Google to take your site seriously then you need to take your site seriously - simply putting up a few pictures and few words sadly will not make you rank. Give Google something to jump up and down about while giving your visitors something enjoyable to read and look forward to going on a boat trip with you!

Comment: Did you had your website on Google Webmaster Tools? If yes, did you changed it there too?

Comment: Can you get testimonials from past customers and put them up there?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like an over-optimization penalty.  You appear to Google to be trying **too hard** for that specific phrase.

I haven't looked into your link profile, but those rankings could also be due to the sites linking to you.  I'm just going to assume your link profile is clean and you don't have any spammy links coming into your site.

If I were you, I would:

- Put your brand name back in your title: Anawangin Trips by Pundaquitboat
- Remove the keyword matching H1, and make this your H1: Boat tours to Anawangin Cove and Capones Island (in the Philippines, province of Zambales)
- Add more pages to your site!

  - FAQ should be an easy one.  Answer the questions that customers are most likely to ask first.
  - You have great pictures, but it would be nice to have more information about the landmarks one might see on a tour.  One page per landmark would be amazing.
  - Information about schedules would be nice.  I also don't see anything on your site about how long your tours are.  I see pics of camping, are all the tours overnight?

Answer (score 0):

Too graphically literate with little content.

Want to place high on Google? Say something about the subject in a way that a human would want to read it. Turn it into a travelogue with a story line starting at departure and describe the trip and the islands visited. What are you going to do at the destination? Is this only a taxi service or a camping trip.

Look up some successful trip outfitters and get ideas as to how they promote and market their services.

If you need to hire someone with combined marketing and writing skills, do so. See if you can get 15 pages out of it. Above all, make it interesting to humans. Google expects natural language over SEO tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: because your page PR is 0.
Get some other web sites to deep-link to you.

Comment: PageRank has little to do with rankings anymore. Plus with the toolbar being very outdated you actually have no idea what the PR is right now or at any given moment of time.

Comment: @JohnConde - Then how come that an almost empty high PR page is always first on Google, while your page full of content is at the bottom?

Comment: Because there are a *lot* more ranking factors that come into play besides size of content (which probably even isn't a ranking factor).